# is prime? in Operations Research

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-programming, constraint-programming, logical-constraints

Is there a way to linearize `is prime?` in Operations Research?

`is prime(n)` being true if $n$ is a prime number or false otherwise.

If it is not possible, which I suspect, is there any other way in either:

- Non linear programming
- Constraint programming

An upper bound of $n$ is known in advance, being any positive natural number.

Comment: Is an upper bound of $n$ known beforehand?

Comment: @worldsmithhelper, yes very good point, I added it to the question!

Comment: Based on the answers, readers don't know whether you want 1) a variable being prime (or not prime) as a constraint in an optimization or feasibility problem (as I interpreted) or 2) an optimization problem whose solution determines whether a number is prime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR**: Enumerate (in advance) all primes $\le$ upper bound on $n$. Check to see whether a variable (declared as integer) equals one of the enumerated primes.

**Details:**
Declare $x$ as integer.

Let $U$ be the upper bound on $x$.

Let $P$ be an $m$ by 1 vector consisting of all primes $\le U$.

Declare $b$ as an $m$ by 1 vector of binary variables.

$x$ is constrained to be prime by $$x = b^TP$$ $$\Sigma b = 1$$

**Edit**:  I am answering the interpretation of the question that a variable being prime (or not prime) is a constraint in an optimization or feasibility problem. Some other answers interpret the question as formulating an optimization problem whose solution determines whether a number is prime.

Comment: Mhh this is more elegant than my solution using absolute values, it also uses less binary variables. Well done!

Comment: If you have the list of all primes in the first place, then you really just need to check if $n$ belongs to that list.

Comment: @Kuifje Exactly, that is my point. I interpreted the question as wanting to constrain variables in an optimization or feasibility problem to be prime (or not prime). Not that we should use optimization as a way of determining prmeness.

Answer (score 2):

In Mixed-Integer Linear Programming, one could consider "prime" as a new type of variables in addition to "continuous", "binary", "integer", "semi-continuous"... Then the algorithm would branch as long a as a variable of type "prime" is not prime in the relaxation. For example if a "prime" variable $x$ has value $4$ in the relaxation, then the algorithm could branch on $x$ with one branch $x \le 3$ and the other $x \ge 5$.

It also seems possible to consider this type of variables in Constraint Programming.

But as far as I know, no MILP or CP solver supports this.

Comment: I agree that this is not supported directly in any solver that I know of. However, some solvers allow the user control over the branching process via callbacks, so it could hypothetically be implemented by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Primality is difficult to check as it requires a statement like "there don't exist two natural numbers $a,b>1$ such that $n=a\cdot b$" which for flexible a $n$ require quantifiers to express. Quantified Mixed Integer (Linear) programming exists as a concept but I am not really aware of any solvers that can solve such problems.

This means we need to somehow "unroll" all possibilities such an quantifier would cover. Let $N$ be the upper bound of $n$ a naive one would be $\prod_{x \in \mathbb{P}} (n-x) = 0$ or some other polynomial. Other primality tests such as the Wilson test $(n-1)!\ \equiv\; -1 \pmod n$ can also be expressed but would result in even higher order polynomials.

Another alternative not using products of variables is to use the absolute value $\forall_{x\in\mathbb{P}\leq N} |n-x| \leq N b_p$ and $\sum_{x\in \mathbb{P}} b_p = 1$ and $b_p$ is a boolean. One could cut the number of equations almost in half by checking divisibility by 2.

There are more compact `is prime` checks and one could systematically search those for some fixed $N$. This would likely be possible using a two level Mixed Integer Quadratic problem where you try to find an constraint matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n+2\times n+2}$ and a constraint vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ that satisfies
$$\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\leq N:   A x \leq \begin{bmatrix}
           m \\
           \text{isprime}(m) \\
           b_1
           \vdots \\
           b_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}$$
where the parent tries to find a such a matrix $A$ and an assignment $x \in \mathbb{R}^a \times \mathbb{B}^{N-a}$ that satisfies this and the $N$ sub problems (each has it's own $m$) try to find counter examples $x$ such that for the $A,b$ from the  parent problem
$$A x \leq \begin{bmatrix}
           m \\
           1-\text{isprime}(m) \\
           b_1
           \vdots \\
           b_{n}
         \end{bmatrix}$$
This counter example can then be used to add a new constraint to the parent problem. If the parent problem becomes unfeasible a bigger $n$ for the dimensions needs to be chosen. Note that only the parent problem is quadratic. If all subproblems are infeasible you found a constraint which encodes `is prime`. Depending how you chose $n$ and whether the parent problem has an appropriate objective it might also be the smallest $n$, a sparse $A$ or have other properties you want and can express in quadratic programming.

Note that Mixed Integer solvers are generally not great in finding feasible solutions a more different approach would be to pick a binary encoding of $n$ to be tested and do a similar find counter example make more constraints loop with a Pseudo boolean or a SAT solver. This will result in binary constraints which can then also be used in a MILP problem. Quantified boolean solvers also exist and there might be a way to "coax" them into finding a solution without bouncing back and forth. Another alternative on that front are [Binary Decision Diagrams](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Ecram/cse505/Fall20/Resources/bdd97.pdf) which are also use to reduce logic in computer chips.

Getting good results using either method with some analysis of the result would probably be worth publishing a paper about. There might be some other way to derive such a look up table however i am not aware of any.

Answer (score 2):

Since primes only have $2$ divisors, $1$ and the number itself, you could use the following program to determine if an integer $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is prime or not :
$$
\max \; x
$$
\begin{align}
\mbox{subject to  }\quad n &= x \cdot y \tag{1} \\ 
x &\in \mathbb{N} \cap [0,n-1] \tag{2}\\
y &\in \mathbb{N} \cap [0,n] \tag{3}
\end{align}

With constraints $(1)-(3)$, you try to decompose $n$ as a product of two integers $x$ and $y$, where $x$ cannot equal $n$. The objective function maximizes $x$. So if the largest $x$ you can find equals $1$, then $n$ is prime. Otherwise it is not.

For example, if $n:=10$, the following solution is optimal: $x=5$, $y=2$. So $n$ is not prime. If $n=11$, the following solution is optimal: $x=1$, $y=11$. So $n$ is prime.

Of course this is not linear, but you can easily linearize the product, and you will have a problem with binary and integer variables that determine if a number $n$ is prime or not.